# Implicit conversion of keys from strings is deprecated. Please use InMemory or LocalFileReference classes. [Laravel/Passport]

Tags: laravel, jwt, laravel-passport

I am using laravel/passport for api authentication Today My old access token isn't working and When i try to generate new access token then i got

> Implicit conversion of keys from strings is deprecated. Please use InMemory or LocalFileReference classes. {"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): Implicit conversion of keys from strings is deprecated. Please use InMemory or LocalFileReference classes.

Anyone have any solution?

Comment: I didn't using `jwt` package directly in `laravel`. I am using `passport`. They are using `jwt`

Comment: In your project `composer.json` add `"lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.3"` and execute `composer update`.

Comment: Thanks man. I downgrade to `lcobucci/jwt:3.3` It's working for me

Answer (score 45, accepted):

`lcobucci/jwt:3.4` has this problem, you can downgrade to 3.3, `composer require lcobucci/jwt:3.3` can resolve it.

Or, In `config\jwt.php` file Change :

```
'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Lcobucci::class,
```

to

```
'jwt' => Tymon\JWTAuth\Providers\JWT\Namshi::class,
```

Comment: What's the difference between these providers?

Comment: For me, it's work using `composer require lcobucci/jwt:3.3.1`. Laravel 5.5

Comment: Where is the config\jwt.php ?

Comment: @ItayMoav-Malimovka on the same location where the `/config/app.php` located.

Comment: @sta Missed the Laravel tag. I am using this lib through another system (oauth league). Ill find it ;-)

Comment: First I tried "composer require lcobucci/jwt" but not working for me,
then I tried composer require llcobucci/jwt": "3.3.
Its working perfectly.
Thanks @sta

Answer (score 8):

As said before, `lcobucci/jwt:3.4` is causing this issue, which can be solved by downgrading to 3.3.*.
However, if you have declared something like this:

```
"lcobucci/jwt": "^3.3.1",
```

you need to remove the `^` because v3.4 would still be downloaded. Please keep in mind, using a newer version might be better because of bugfixes and other stuff, so make sure to update the respective logic to work with a newer version of the dependecy.

Comment: Thanks, i got this error today with Passport v7 and adding "lcobucci/jwt": "3.3.1" to composer.json solved it for me.

Answer (score 0):

A new version of Laravel Passport, v10.1.0 was released today that fixes this issue.